# Insert skeleton in 3D model programmatically

Tags: kinect, 3d-modelling, 3d-model, skeletal-mesh

## Background

---

I'm working on a project where a user gets scanned by a Kinect (v2). The result will be a generated 3D model which is suitable for use in games.

The scanning aspect is going quite well, and I've generated some good user models.
Example:
[image: A 3D model of a user]
*Note: This is just an early test model. It still needs to be cleaned up, and the stance needs to change to properly read skeletal data.*

## Problem

---

The problem I'm currently facing is that I'm unsure how to place skeletal data inside the generated 3D model. I can't seem to find a program that will let me insert the skeleton in the 3D model programmatically. I'd like to do this either via a program that I can control programmatically, or adjust the 3D model file in such a way that skeletal data gets included within the file.

## What have I tried

---

I've been looking around for similar questions on Google and StackOverflow, but they usually refer to either motion capture or skeletal animation. I know Maya has the option to insert skeletons in 3D models, but as far as I could find that is always done by hand. Maybe there is a more technical term for the problem I'm trying to solve, but I don't know it.

I do have a train of thought on how to achieve the skeleton insertion. I imagine it to go like this:

1. Scan the user and generate a 3D model with Kinect;

   1.2. Clean user model, getting rid of any deformations or unnecessary information. Close holes that are left in the clean up process.
2. Scan user skeletal data using the Kinect.

   2.2. Extract the skeleton data.
    2.3. Get joint locations and store as xyz-coordinates for 3D space. Store bone length and directions.
3. Read 3D skeleton data in a program that can create skeletons.
4. Save the new model with inserted skeleton.

## Question

---

Can anyone recommend (I know, this is perhaps "opinion based") a program to read the skeletal data and insert it in to a 3D model? Is it possible to utilize Maya for this purpose?

Thanks in advance.

*Note: I opted to post the question here and not on Graphics Design Stack Exchange (or other Stack Exchange sites) because I feel it's more coding related, and perhaps more useful for people who will search here in the future. Apologies if it's posted on the wrong site.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tricky part of your question is what you mean by *"inserting the skeleton"*. Typically bone data is very separate from your geometry, and stored in different places in your scene graph (with the bone data being hierarchical in nature).

There are file formats you can export to where you might establish some association between your geometry and skeleton, but that's very format-specific as to how you associate the two together (ex: FBX vs. Collada).

Probably the closest thing to "inserting" or, more appropriately, "attaching" a skeleton to a mesh is skinning. There you compute weight assignments, basically determining how much each bone influences a given vertex in your mesh.

This is a tough part to get right (both programmatically and artistically), and depending on your quality needs, is often a semi-automatic solution at best for the highest quality needs (commercial games, films, etc.) with artists laboring over tweaking the resulting weight assignments and/or skeleton.

There are algorithms that get pretty sophisticated in determining these weight assignments ranging from simple heuristics like just assigning weights based on nearest line distance (very crude, and will often fall apart near tricky areas like the pelvis or shoulder) or ones that actually consider the mesh as a solid volume (using voxels or tetrahedral representations) to try to assign weights. Example: http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/11/volumetric-heat-diffusion-skinning/

However, you might be able to get decent results using an algorithm like delta mush which allows you to get a bit sloppy with weight assignments but still get reasonably smooth deformations.

Now if you want to do this externally, pretty much any 3D animation software will do, including free ones like Blender. However, skinning and character animation in general is something that tends to take quite a bit of artistic skill and a lot of patience, so it's worth noting that it's not quite as easy as it might seem to make characters leap and dance and crouch and run and still look good even when you have a skeleton in advance. That weight association from skeleton to geometry is the toughest part. It's often the result of many hours of artists laboring over the deformations to get them to look right in a wide range of poses.

Comment: Thanks your answer gave a good insight in what I needed to know. The link for volumetric heat diffusion skinning is very helpful (love wolfire). Unfortunately I'm currently in the stage of programmatically cleaning up the 3d model, and after that will continue on inserting the skeleton. So until that time I won't be sure this is "the answer". I'll make sure to come back and accept it once I've researched it some more and tried implementing it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: One thing you might want to do is pick a format for exporting these game assets. FBX is pretty popular and widely-supported (Unity, Unreal Engine, etc) since it's from AutoDesk (kind of a monopolizer of the 3D industry). After that it's a matter of understanding the format (in FBX's case, they have an SDK you can use to avoid dealing with the file format details). Then you're free to export that rigged asset completely without the aid of other software -- the bulk of the work then boils down to coming up with a good implementation of weight assignment.

Comment: Another thing in case you might not be aware (though you already mentioned something about the pose) is that you generally want to scan in those characters in a kind of T-pose (like Da Vinci) -- arms out, legs spread. The main reason is because these weight map assignments trip the most over those joint areas connecting limbs to the torso -- since the vertices are so close to the torso (upper chest, pelvis, e.g) that it's hard to generate a weight assignment for skinning if they're not spread apart. You can also do something a little more relaxed and natural, but the T-pose is useful if you...

Comment: ... want to allow the characters a full range of motion (ex: raising their arms in the air which is a very difficult case to support while looking nice).

Comment: Ike I absolutely love your comments! Yeah the pose in the example above was just a test case which I used for 3D printing. I'm fully aware of the problems that stance brings with it. I've been think on what the optimal stance might be, but I guess you just gave the solution. I was personally leaning more towards a natural arms to the side stance, since the scan takes a while to complete (30 to 60 seconds) though I can improve on this by building a rig. Doing the Da Vinci stance might be difficult to do for such a period, and movement corrupts the scan. Depending on ...

Comment: ... the time the rig could do the scan I would opt for the Da Vinci pose or natural pose, though ideally I'd want to be able to support the full range of body movements. Just as FYI this system will be mainly used for getting easy quick models that can be used in games. For me personally I'd only want to make a quick demo illustrating it's potential. The idea is that people can use the generated models and skeletons and improve on them as they see fit (changing the 3d model, textures, skeleton/skinning and animations as they see fit)

Comment: One of the tough parts about weight assignment is that it's really tough to do a great job for a full range of motion. That's why the Da Vinci pose is popular, since if you imagine a person doing jumping jacks, it captures like the "middle" of that full range of motion. That way you're not deforming quite as much from the base pose to do it (and the weighting issues don't show up so much). If you choose a more relaxed, natural position, that might work better when the character is making more natural motions like just walking casually, but it becomes harder to support like an acrobatic case.

Comment: Hmm I see. For my own and other people's sake I'll have to go with the full range then (or try at least ;)) since the probability is high that eventually someone will want to use that. In matter of fact the demo case I had in mind was a simple fighting game. That would already require some acrobatic poses (street fighter/tekken style).

Comment: Maybe some kind of compromise would work -- like arms at 45 degrees, legs slightly spread apart. It'll shift more of the challenge to you to programmatically come up with good weights, so you might choose a balance between the ideal pose for comfortable scanning vs. one that is easiest to generate a good set of weights depending on how far you get with the weight assignment/skinning side of the work.

Comment: Hi @Ike, is it possible to get in touch with me for a potential collaboration?

Comment: @George Asda Sorry for the super late reply but I'm afraid I'm currently so wrapped up in my own work to do a collaboration. Thanks for the offer though!